# overriding toString in scala and creating a second toString method with default parameters

Tags: scala, overriding, tostring, default-parameters

I have a complex-number-related class for which I wrote the following code:

```
override def toString: String = toString()

def toString(precision: Int = 2, showImag:Boolean = true): String = ???
```

The implementation of the second method is not important. The problem with this is that `toString()` will call `toString` and will recurse endlessly. I could replace `toString()` with `toString(2)`, but I think that is ugly, as the 2 is already implied. Is there a way to use the second function without specifying parameters or renaming the function?

---

**EDIT**:

As the answer and comments showed it isn't possible (read their explanation why). I realized that a way to get around this is by creating an private method with a different name that is called by the other two public methods and contains the actual implementation, like so:

```
override def toString: String = toStringImpl(2, true)

def toString(precision: Int = 2, showImag:Boolean = true): String = toStringImpl(precision, showImag)

private def toStringImpl(precision: Int, showImag:Boolean): String = ???
```

You could say that this is more lines of code and you could say that it indeed doesn't give a parameter that was already default. Both approaches work and I think it would be subjective to further discuss which approach is better as both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: You could use implicit parameters, I guess for the precision parameter.

Comment: @Rjk how do you mean?

Comment: Passing "2" is not ugly in my opinion. Moreover, that is the correct way of doing what you want. You have to somehow differentiate two signatures. And in the end, you still have a parameterless "toString"

Comment: @Nebril I just wanted to know if tthere was another way to differentiate between the rwo. From what I gather in the comments and answers, there isn't?

Comment: @coolcat007, when the scala code is compiled, method `toString(1)` is replaced with proper java. Default values are lost and explicit values are used where the method is called: `toString(1, toString$default$2())` (compiler creates such names). However, when you call only `toString()` the compiler doesn't change anything, because such function already exists. On runtime you'll get stack overflow but compiler doesn't care. You could use java decompiler on your project to see what really happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the second function without specifying parameters or renaming the function?

Whatever you do, `toString()` will call the `toString()` inherited from `Any`, because it's the most specific matching method.